# Flask-Wtforms QuerySelectField, Too many values to unpack error

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

## Hello everyone. I'm here to ask for a bit of help with an error I'm getting in python. For reference, I'm using Flask, SQLALCHEMY, Flask-wtforms, and SQLite.

I'm attempting to use QuerySelectField. However, I keep getting this error:

"Too many values to unpack (Expected two)"

I have no idea of how to resolve this. Not a clue or any direction to go with.
I would attempt to better detail this problem, but I don't understand it at all. Other Stack Overflow users have asked similar questions. However, the ones that I have seen have been told that this error is caused by deprecation in Wtf-forms (At least from my understanding).

[Why does Flask WTForms and WTForms-SQLAlchemy QuerySelectField produce too many values to unpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353190/why-does-flask-wtforms-and-wtforms-sqlalchemy-queryselectfield-produce-too-many)

Where this may very well be the cause of the error they're getting, I don't believe it to be the cause of the error I'm getting. The reason is that to do this I'm actually following a tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9W2ul2VRRc

This tutorial has database models that are incredibly similar to mine. I follow his instructions almost exactly, making small changes that are needed because the project I'm working on is not contained in only one singular file. Those changes are, to my knowledge, as follows:

1: I'm querying the names of tables that I've created, not the names of those tables he has created.

2: I have a models, routes, Init, etc python file and therefore the classes and functions he has created are in slightly different locations.

Changes I do not believe to be the problem or root cause of this issue.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or help anyone can give me. Even if you cannot or chose not to help, I greatly appreciate you reading this far.

Here is the relevant code:

## Model (Relevant code in the models.py)

```
from datetime import datetime
from app import db, login
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

class GuildModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    GuildName = db.Column(db.String(300), index=True, unique=True)
    GuildDescription = db.Column(db.String(64))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Guild {}>'.format(self.GuildName)
```

## Form and function (Relevant code that is located in the forms.py)

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, DataRequired, Email, EqualTo
from app.models import UserModel, GuildModel
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

class GuildRegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    GuildName = StringField('Please enter the name of your guild', validators=[DataRequired()])
    GuildDescriptionForm = StringField('Describe your guild!', validators=[DataRequired()])
    SubmitGuild = SubmitField('Create Guild!')

def GuildQuery():
    return GuildModel.query

class GuildSetForm(FlaskForm):
    GuildOneName = QuerySelectField(query_factory=GuildQuery, allow_blank=True)
```

## Routes (Relevant code in the routes.py)

```
from app import app
from app import db
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from app.forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegistrationForm, GuildRegistrationForm, GuildSetForm
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user
from app.models import UserModel, GuildModel

@app.route('/SetGuilds')
def SetGuilds():
    form = GuildSetForm()
    return render_template('GuildSelect.html', form=form)
```

## Template file (All code in GuildSelect.html)

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p>
        {{ form.GuildOneName.label }}
        {{ form.GuildOneName(size=2) }}

    </p>
</form>
```

## TraceBack Error

```
File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/DevBuild/app/routes.py", line 66, in SetGuilds
    return render_template('GuildSelect.html', form=form)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/DevBuild/app/templates/GuildSelect.html", line 4, in top-level template code
    {{ form.GuildOneName(size=2) }}
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 155, in __call__
    return self.meta.render_field(self, kwargs)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/meta.py", line 56, in render_field
    return field.widget(field, **render_kw)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 323, in __call__
    for val, label, selected in field.iter_choices():
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms_sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 107, in iter_choices
    for pk, obj in self._get_object_list():
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms_sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 100, in _get_object_list
    self._object_list = list((text_type(get_pk(obj)), obj) for obj in query)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms_sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 100, in <genexpr>
    self._object_list = list((text_type(get_pk(obj)), obj) for obj in query)
  File "/home/z/Desktop/GuildsSocialBuilds/DevBuild/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms_sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 189, in get_pk_from_identity
    cls, key = identity_key(instance=obj)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Could you edit the post and show us the code (as well as the traceback) where the error is occurring?

Comment: I will certainly add the traceback error, however, the actual error is occurring in an odd location. The actual fields.py file of SQL alchemy.

Comment: That is fine. Just supply enough code to recreate the error.

Comment: Alright, give me one moment.

Comment: This should be enough to reliably reproduce the error.

Comment: The error is not occurring in SQLAlchemy, but rather in your `routes.py` line 66 and in your `GuildSelect.html` file. What is the kwarg `size=2` that is passed?

Comment: Size = 2 Is the variable used to control how big something like a flask search bar is. This is still here because I wanted to set a minimum size for the choice options, however, I don't believe it works. Removing it does not resolve the issue

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that `GuildQuery` was returning a `Query` obj. I am not able to reproduce the error. I am able to see the SelectField. [Here](https://gist.github.com/kaistullich/4083783f286cd95f5bcb8a2b72b1bea2) is the code

Comment: Actually, your code showed me exactly what I needed! The tutorial I was following was using a separate download to perform a QuerySelectField which was not working for me. With your import of
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
I was able to resolve the problem.
Thank you very much for your help. So that you can get reputation points I suggest you write a full answer. If this question was reasonably well put together I would honestly very much appreciate an upvote.