# flask wtforms-alchemy QuerySelectField ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

i am trying to create sign up form using **flask-wtf**, and **wtforms-alchemy** 
on this form i try create selectfield, which the value is query from my models. 
but i'am always get this error:

```
 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

this my **code**:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

def choose_domicile():
    return Domicile.query

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    domicile = QuerySelectField(u'Domicile', query_factory=choose_domicile)


@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def signup():
        form = RegisterFormView()
        try:
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                new_user = Data(name=form.name.data, domicile=form.domicile.data)
                db.session.add(new_user)
                db.session.commit()
                return "Success"
        except:
            return "Failed"

        return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

and this my **signup.html**:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="/signup">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.name) }}
    {{ form.domicile }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my package versions is **flask-wtf==0.14.2** and **wtforms-alchemy==0.16.7**

i have try to follow this [Why does Flask WTForms and WTForms-SQLAlchemy QuerySelectField produce too many values to unpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353190/why-does-flask-wtforms-and-wtforms-sqlalchemy-queryselectfield-produce-too-many) , but i am still confused how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a function as following which can be passed as a get_pk paramater.

```
def get_pk(obj):
    return str(obj)
```

and then do the following change

```
domicile = QuerySelectField(u'Domicile', query_factory=choose_domicile, get_pk=get_pk)
```

I am assuming that you have define `__str__` in model class else return pk in get_pk

Comment: Also, `return repr(obj)` will work if `__repr__` is defined in the model class.